# Vue Router go to top on new page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Right now, in my Vue app, when I click a `<router-link>`, it goes to the page, but to the same scroll level as the previous page (because the link simply replaces the component).

I was wondering if there was a `vue-router` feature that makes the page go to the top, or I need to use some other JS programming to achieve this.

Thanks much for the help.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Vue router has several guards and functions that are called before, during and after route changes. In your case, there is a dedicated function that allows you to override the default behaviour of scrolling, named [`scrollBehavior`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#async-scrolling). It is called with two [route objects](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object) and an object containing an x and y coordinate, and maybe a selector that selects an element on the page to use as an offset.

To use it, change the code that defines your router and add the `scrollBehavior` function:

```
// src/router.js
const router = new VueRouter({
  // What you previously had here, such as routes

  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    return { x: 0, y: 0 };
  }
});

export default router;
```

Comment: how to make this scrollup smoother

Comment: Hey @JenuelGanawed . The comment section is not meant for new questions. If you want to ask a question related to this question, you can link this question in your new question and ask a follow-up question.

Comment: oh sorry @Sumurai8

Comment: This approach fails for me with the error
 ```87:18  error  'to' is defined but never used             no-unused-vars
 87:22  error  'from' is defined but never used           no-unused-vars
 87:28  error  'savedPosition' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars ```

Comment: That is your linter warning that you are not using the function's parameters... which are indeed unused. I included the parameters in this example so it is easier to modify if you need them, but since the function just returns an object with x and y set to 0, you can omit all three parameters.

Comment: for smooth scrolling -> https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html#smooth-scrolling

Comment: @JenuelGanawed you can use this
`const router = createRouter({
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if (to.hash) {
      return {
        el: to.hash,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      }
    }
  }
})`
check [this](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/scroll-behavior.html) out for more info